# SQL with nested group function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle db 11g

I have a table 'EMPLOYEES' like this...

```
ID  JOB_ID      SALARY
100 AD_PRES     24000
101 AD_VP       17000
102 AD_VP       17000
103 IT_PROG     9000
104 IT_PROG     6000
107 IT_PROG     4200
124 ST_MAN      5800
141 ST_CLERK    3500
142 ST_CLERK    3100
143 ST_CLERK    2600
144 ST_CLERK    2500
149 SA_MAN      10500
174 SA_REP      11000
176 SA_REP      8600
178 SA_REP      7000
200 AD_ASST     4400
201 MK_MAN      13000
202 MK_REP      6000
205 AC_MGR      12000
206 AC_ACCOUNT  8300
```

And I want to get the maximum of average salary of each job(job_id) and the job of it.

I firstly tried this and It resulted in error

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(salary)) AS max_avg_salary, job_id
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id;

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I finally made it with this code

```
WITH emp AS (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id FROM employees GROUP BY job_id)
SELECT e1.avg_salary AS max_avg_salary, e1.job_id
FROM emp e1 JOIN (SELECT MAX(avg_salary) AS max_avg_salary FROM emp) e2
ON e1.avg_salary = e2.max_avg_salary;

MAX_AVG_SALARY  JOB_ID
24000           AD_PRES
```

What I want to know is..

1. Why my first code makes error?
2. Is there any better (more simple or easier) way than my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
select job_id, salary
  from (  select job_id,
                 avg (salary) salary,
                 rank () over (order by avg (salary) desc) rnk
            from employees
        group by job_id)
 where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]  ... Unless you meant to get just a single answer, in which case the other respondent's solution should work and I'll offer a variation:

**Non-Oracle:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM
        (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id
            FROM employees
            GROUP BY job_id
        ) a
    ORDER BY a.avg_salary DESC
```

Littlefoot pointed out, quite correctly, that **this won't work on Oracle** because of the TOP 1.  You should pick his solution.  I'm going to leave this here for any non-Oracle folks:

However, the asker himself, C Park, suggested an Oracle-compatible variation on this using  ROWNUM.  He's tested it and it worked for him so this will work in..

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id
            FROM employees
            GROUP BY job_id
        ) a
    ORDER BY a.avg_salary DESC
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There's no `TOP` in Oracle, as far as I can tell, so ... I'm not sure that it'll help.

Comment: @Littlefoot - Argh, you're right.  I'm a SQL Server guy - and not the first time I've done that either.  Functionally, TOP1 it's so simple that I don't have that moment of pause "wait, am I doing something that might be out of bounds in another database".  Oh well, I'm going to up-vote you and go to bed.  Have a good one!

Comment: @C.Park - You're welcome - but Littlefoot is right, there's no TOP 1 in Oracle that's why you're getting an error.  You should pick his answer.

Comment: Thanks. but that code results in error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: And I found a way replace SELECT TOP in Oracle.. Like This `SELECT *
FROM
        (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id
            FROM employees
            GROUP BY job_id
            ORDER BY avg_salary DESC
        ) a
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;` and it works well. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @C.Park - I like that, it's very clean.  I will have to remember ROWNUM the next time I'm tempted to use TOP 1 for an Oracle person.   :-)

Comment: @C Park - I added your suggested variation (using ROWNUM) to my answer.  Thanks for trying that and letting me know that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your query like this,

```
SELECT MAX(avg_salary) 
  FROM (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id
          FROM employees
         GROUP BY job_id);
```

or if you want to display the job id also,

```
SELECT avg_salary, job_id
  FROM (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary, job_id
          FROM employees
         GROUP BY job_id
         ORDER BY avg_salary DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: You *forgot* to include JOB_ID to the result.

Comment: ah, ok, i added another query to include the JOB_ID, thanks

Comment: Much better :) Thank you!